# TeamCity strips domain from vcs usernames

Tags: git, teamcity

I have setup TeamCity in our company. There is a slight problem with the GIT integration. TeamCity always strips the domain from all GIT usernames, so 'mail@foo.com' is shown as 'mail'. I would rather like it to display the full email-address, because the prefix isn't always unique.

Answer (score 2):

For people with 'vanity' domain emails googling it seems to be under `Edit VCS Root` > `Show advanced options` > `Username style`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kayH.png

[image]